# Cassandra: Model large list of items with user defined order

Tags: cassandra, nosql

Simple use case. A list of say up to 3M items.
The user can re-arrange items in the list (move to top, bottom, up, down).
List is served in paginated manner.

So far we came up with the following solution.
First CF is to map item id into a fractional position (big decimal).

```
 create table positions (
      list_id UUID,
      item_id UUID,
      position text,
      PRIMARY KEY(list_id, item_id)      
  );
```

By fractional position I mean the following:

Let's say we have initial positions of items defined by column names:

```
1 2 3 4 5
---------
a b c d e
```

when we want to insert an item between 2 and 3, we simply create a decimal fraction which will provides us a correct sort order without having to re-shift the rest of the items:

```
1 2 2.5 3 4 5
-------------
a b  X  c d e
```

Second cf is to sort items by position:

```
 create table items (
      list_id UUID,
      item_id UUID,
      position text,
      PRIMARY KEY(list_id, position)      
  );
```

Obviously pagination will be done using N+1 limit selects of the 'items' table and item_id taken from a previous page.

To insert item (insert_id) before another item (before_id) we could use the following pseudo-code:

```
BigDecimal before_position = (select position from positions where list_id = '...' and item_id = 'before_id')

List<item_id> list = (select item_id from items where list_id = '...' and position = 'before_position' order by desc limit 2)
BigDecimal before_before_id = list[2]

before_before_position =  (select position from positions where list_id = '...' and item_id = 'before_before_id')
BigDecimal insert_position = (before_position + before_before_position) / 2;

insert into positions (list_id, item_id, position) values ('...', 'insert_id', insert_position.toPlainString());

insert into items (list_id, item_id, position) values ('...', 'insert_id', insert_position.toPlainString());
```

Are we doing it right?

What we do not like in this solution is that fractional positions may grow quite big after a lot of item re-arrangements (especially if insertions happen to be at a same position like in "move-to-top" use case). We should probably "maintain" this by normalizing fractions back into true integer positions by a scheduled background job.

Another problem is that it does not seem to be possible to insert an item efficiently into a random ordinal position. We will have to scan the entire column family to achieve this.